# How to fix a bg image that doesn't cover the entire page on mobile version?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, background

I want to make set a bg image for one of my website pages made with Wordpress, but on the mobile version it keeps its normal aspect ratio. Here is the website page http://zm.jcreator.eu/

```
css:

.entry-content #fit {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

The code snippet in the page editor:

<img id="fit" src="http://zm.jcreator.eu/wp- 
content/uploads/2019/03/home_1.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Make it bigger, or make the screen smaller.... lol ... In any case that's not a background image, so any attempts to use `background-` will fail as it's an `<img` tag.  I might add it will be more challenging to do with an image tag as you have less control over that with CSS and it's more dependent on the structure of the page.

Comment: There isn't enough information given here. The CSS selector you declared is not even implemented in the short code snippet. Please provide more info so we can help better.

Comment: If I understand you, you could add this code `height: 100vh; background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to approach it.

1) Position your image absolutely within the container.

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
   <img id="fit" src="..." alt/>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we assume that you want your image to take 100% of width and height of the browser, then your css should look like this (notice I'm ignoring the entry-content, because I'm not quite sure if the rest of the content will be in a new div or not - it seems very unclear in your example).

```
.img-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.img-wrapper img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

The gimmick of this approach - it will only ever work well for certain scenarios decided by the aspect ratio of the image. A way around it wold be to use a JavaScript snippet that you can bind on document load and resize. Then you could use the following JavaScript to calculate the best size of the image for a certain scenario:

```
function checkImg() {
    var img = document.getElementById('fit'));
    var section = document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content')[0];
    var imgheight = img.offsetHeight;
    var sectionheight = section.offsetHeight;
    var imgwidth = img.offsetWidth;
    var sectionwidth = section.offsetWidth;

        var imgRatio = imgheight / imgwidth;
        var scrRatio = sectionheight / sectionwidth;

        if (scrRatio > imgRatio) {
            var finalHeight = sectionheight;
            var scale = finalHeight / imgheight;
            var finalWidth = imgwidth * scale;
        } else {
            var finalWidth = sectionwidth;
            var scale = finalWidth / imgwidth;
            var finalHeight = imgheight * scale;
        }
        img.style.height = finalHeight + 'px';
        img.style.width = finalWidth + 'px';
    }
}
```

Remember it is crucial you run this function once the document is loaded and not just ready, because otherwise the function won't get the correct size of the image if it's executed before it's loaded.

In the same time if you don't trigger it on resize, the width and height of the image won't change.

2) Use the css background properties. As ArtisticPhoenix pointed out, you cannot use background properties on an image tag. You can however set the image as a background for an element. Then you could use the following:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that you are not going to put the image in here with the img tag, but instead you will have to specify the source for the background-image property in your CSS like the following:

```
.img-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image:url('http://zm.jcreator.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/home_1.jpg');
}
```

Since you're using WordPress, you would probably like to use an image that you choose in the CMS. In that case, you just need to specify the background-image with inline styles:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image:url('<?php echo your_php_function_to_get_img_url(); ?>')">
  </div>
</div>
```